# jQuery event not triggered after npm update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on an application. Before I was using the jquery_ujs gem and now switched to using it through npm (webpack). After switching, when the application is making put/post request, it is making a successful request (that I can confirm through console) but the ajax:success and ajax:error are not triggered on the

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', ‘.test', function(event, xhr){
//code
});
```

I tried using :

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(‘.test’, function(event,xhr){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) it should be:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr){
  //code
});
```

Not:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess('.test', function(event, xhr){
  //code
});
```